# Including a new table in the DBContext made with CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

We have a Data library they have built it with CodeFirst.
Now I ran a SQL command and added a new table to that database.
But Now I want to also see its generated object class, its DBContext definitions ,etc.. in the code first code so I can use them in my LINQ queries.
So what I did was following number 3 method from this MSDN page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx

But it didn't do it right. For example it did not add any definition for this new table to DBContext.cs file, for example all my other tables that used to be there are defined like this:

```
DbSet<Zipcode> Zipcodes { get; set; }
```

But it has not added anything for me.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unaware of a way to simply add a new table and have it 'plug-n-play' with your existing model without manual work. The two options I know of are:

1. Rebuild the model using Code First from DB and include your added table
2. Manually create the table as a class and add the DbSet and entity in the OnModelCreating method in your model

Comment: I started with number one above actually. So you mean I should still manually add the DbSet definition to my context?

Comment: Nope, you wouldn't need to manually add the DBSet in that case. With #1 route, delete the original model and all associated classes first. Then create a new model (same name if you want as original) with all the tables you want like you originally did the first time you created the model. No manual work adding DBSets and such if you delete the original model and add the new model with all the tables you want.

Comment: ok How do I delete the original model ? This thing that I see most of it as POCO classes that their name is the same as name of the table in DB .

Comment: Usually I have my model and all table objects in a folder so I just delete the folder. Let's pretend your solution is set up like: Solution -> Domain ->Model. Delete model from there. If it's not in a containing folder then select the model and each supporting class and delete. There isn't a quick delete model option :(

Answer (score 0):

Code First from Database only works when you already have a database. If you want to add a new table, you will have to start using Code-First(alone), that means: add the entity **Zipcode** to the model, **DbSet** to the **DbContext** and after that when you compile it will generate de table in the database.